# Check Intel X540 NIC temperature in Windows 11

Tags: networking, network-adapter

I recently upgraded to an Intel X540 NIC in my Windows 11 PC, because that's what everybody recommended. It is directly connected to my server via RJ45. Before attempting to swap a faulty fan, I would like to see the temperature of the NIC, so I can do some before/after comparisons.

[I saw](https://community.intel.com/t5/Ethernet-Products/Intel-X540-T1-periodically-lost-link/td-p/1251744?profile.language=ja) that I can use Intel's PROSet... software? to query the temperature via PowerShell, but unfortunately Intel has discontinued it, and said Windows 10 is going to be the last version. Quite a bummer.

Any clue how I can check the temperature? I don't mind spinning up a Windows 10 VM via Hyper-V, and then install Intel PROSet if that's possible, but doing it directly in Windows 11 (or via WSL) would be nice.

Comment: @Gantendo No. That doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you want, but it works.

Buy a cheap USB temperature sensor, and place it on the heatsink or maybe the opposite side of the PCB.